# how to join two pandas dataframe on specific column

Tags: join, pandas

I have 1st pandas dataframe which looks like this

```
order_id buyer_id caterer_id item_id  qty_purchased  
    387      139          1       7              3   
    388      140          1       6              3   
    389      140          1       7              3   
    390       36          1       9              3   
    391       79          1       8              3   
    391       79          1       12              3   
    391       79          1       7              3   
    392       72          1       9              3   
    392       72          1       9              3   
    393       65          1       9              3   
    394       65          1      10              3   
    395      141          1      11              3   
    396      132          1      12              3   
    396      132          1      15              3   
    397       31          1      13              3   
    404       64          1      14              3   
    405      146          1      15              3
```

And the 2nd dataframe looks like this

```
 item_id meal_type
      6       Veg
      7       Veg
      8       Veg
      9    NonVeg
     10       Veg
     11       Veg
     12       Veg
     13    NonVeg
     14       Veg
     15    NonVeg
     16    NonVeg
     17       Veg
     18       Veg
     19    NonVeg
     20       Veg
     21       Veg
```

I want to join this two data frames on item_id column. So that the final data frame should contain item_type where it has a match with item_id.

I am doing following in python

`pd.merge(segments_data,meal_type,how='left',on='item_id')`

But it gives me all `nan` values

Comment: I think you can check equality `dtypes` of both columns `item_id`, `print segments_data.dtypes`,  `print meal_type.dtypes`. I think `dtypes` have to be same, not `object` and `int` .

Comment: @jezrael  I didn't get you

Comment: @jezrael  `item_id` is a string type.

Comment: @jezrael Yep. both the columns are string type

Comment: You can try cast both columns to `int` and then try `merge` : `segments_data['item_id'] = segments_data['item_id'].astype(int)`, `meal_type['item_id'] = meal_type['item_id'].astype(int)`, maybe there are whitespaces...

Comment: @jezrael Thanks alot.. Yup its working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check `types` by  [`dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) of both columns (names) to join on.

If there are different, you can cast them, because you need same `dtypes`. Sometimes `numeric` columns are `string` columns, but looks like `numbers`.

If there are both same `string` types, maybe help cast both of them to `int`. Problem can be some `whitespaces`:

```
segments_data['item_id'] = segments_data['item_id'].astype(int) 
meal_type['item_id'] = meal_type['item_id'].astype(int)

pd.merge(segments_data,meal_type,how='left',on='item_id')
```